# intro screen still shows after first time app run

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I launch my app for the first time the splash screen opens then the intro screen opens and when I press done the main activity opens but when I exit the app and reopen it the intro screen still shows up I've been searching for a solution for ages and I'm a newbie can you please help me.

**Splash Screen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView vidHolder;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        initialize();

    }

    private void initialize() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //start your activity here
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, introscreen.class));
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

**Intro Screen.java**

```
  ViewPager viewpager;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introscreen);
        initialize();

        viewpager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        introAdapter adapter = new introAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    private void initialize() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //start your activity here
                startActivity(new Intent(introscreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1200000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".introscreen"
            android:exported="true">


        </activity>
```

Comment: First create preference for your app. once the user goes intro screen save the the state Boolean or  something... Then launch main activity... After sometimes user launch the app check in splash screen user visited or not if yes mean launch main activity

Comment: can you help me and show a code on how to make this possible

Answer (score 1):

Shared preference will be of help here. You should save a Boolean value with shared preference when you click *DONE*.

In **IntroScreen.java**, do this.
Permit my Kotlin please.

```
done.setOnClickListener {
   initialize()
   // Save a value to shared preference
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context).edit()
      .putBoolean("first_time", true)
      .commit()
}
```

Then when next splash screen launches, check the value in shared preference. If it's *true*, then the app is not launching for the first time, launch MainActivity next.

In SplashScreen.java, do this;

```
   private initialize() {
       val handler = Handler()
       val runnable = Runnable() {
          // check if it's the first launch, from shared preference.
          val isNotFirstTime = Preference manager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context)
                   .getBoolean("first_time", false)
          val intent = if (isNotFirstTime) {
              // If it's not the first time, launch MainActivity
              Intent(this@SplashScreen, MainActivity::class.java)
          } else {
              // If it's the first time, launch IntroScreen
              Intent(this@SplashScreen, IntroScreen::class.java)
          }
          //start your activity here
          startActivity(intent)
          finish()
       } 
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
   }
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Everything okay. But use constant keys...

Comment: val is in kotlin right? I have a java project what should I write instead? and what is constant keys?

Comment: While you use **val handler = expr** in _Kotlin_, you use **final handler = expr** in _Java_. They are keywords for declaring immutable values or expressions. Reference the [docs](https://openjdk.org/jeps/286) for clarification. I'm a Kotlin guy. :)   Please, if the answer was useful to you, accept it.